# File and common data in form

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, validation, file-upload

im try upload a image from a form with Codeigniter and Ajax. I create the next form structure:

```
<?php
$config = array('class' => "small-12 columns no-left-margins",'id'=>"form_$i", 'enctype'=>"multipart/form-data");
echo form_open_multipart('', $config); 
?>
<!-- file, text, and text area inputs -->
<?php 
echo form_close(); 
?>
<a href="#" class="button tiny right" id="submit" value="upload">Guardar</a>
```

The Ajax request is:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var datos = $(this).serializeArray();
   $.ajax({
      url: 'guardarNuevoProducto',
      type: 'POST',
      data: datos
   });

});
```

And the controller action code is:

```
// uploadPicture_rules is the index of the $config array that contains the picture   //validation rules
$picRules = $this->config->item('uploadPicture_rules');

$this->load->library('upload', $picRules);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
   echo json_encode(array('st'=>0, 'msg' => $this->upload->display_errors()));
}else{
   echo json_encode(array('st'=>0, 'msg' => 'Successfully Submiited'));
}
```

And have the next file-upload validation rules:

```
$config['uploadPicture_rules'] = Array(
   'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png', 
   'max_size' =>'100',
   'upload_path' => '/assets'
);
```

All form values are checked correctly, but the file_uploader says:

> {"st":0,"msg":"You did not select a file to upload."}

Any ideas ?. I have a wrong congiruation ?.

Answer (score 0):

form_open() change to form_open_multipart()

Comment: thanks for reply, i did the change, but the ajax request return same error.